# Create a wifi hotspot from ethernet connexion using D-Link DWA 160

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

How can I create a Wi-Fi in my house using the ethernet connection that I have?

Right now I can connect one computer to internet via ethernet. I bought a D-Link DWA 160 B2 wireless adapter. From what I read I should be able to put it in my computer, and it would create a hotspot so I could connect my phone and any other devices to the internet. I installed the driver that came with the D-Link. I created an ad-hoc network via Vista, but I don't know how to make that network connect to the ethernet connection to be able to share wireless internet.

Thank you!!

PS: We have two computers: one runs vista, one runs Ubuntu. But I'm a very beginner with Ubuntu, so I can't even figure out how to install the D-Link on there... I have Wine but the installation driver doesn't run correctly even with Wine so I need to install D-Link myself (then figure out how to use it as a router, as mentioned above). If you can help me create a hotspot from either Vista or Ubuntu, it will be great!

Comment: You could have bought a cheap wifi access point for the same price & not had to leave one of the computers on 24/7 to use it.

Comment: Hello, could you suggest one with link to amazon or best buy please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I read things correctly then this is your current setup:

```
   Single device via Ethernet --------------------- Whatever provides your IN
```

But you have multiple devices. Some which can connect wired, some which need to fall back to a wireless connection. The default solution for this is:

```
   ((|))       ((|))
     |           |                       
   Phone       Laptop                   ((|))
                                          |
   Single device via Ethernet ----------Router---- Whatever provides your IN
                                       /
   Another device via Ethernet--------
```

The added device which I called router is now the single devices connecting to whatever provides your Internet.  It is sharing this connection with other devices, routing local traffic between local devices (e.g. your laptop can connect your desktop without using the Internet).  For this you will need to set up your own subnet.

Usually this is trivially done since what often is called a home router is in fact a multi device with router, **wireless access point**, build in wired Ethernet switch, firewall and DHCP server.

The last makes it trivial to use DHCP to configure a typical home setup.

The Wireless Access point part is what you are looking for to connect your phone etc. via WiFi.

These things are usually cheap, use little power and make no noise.

---

Now to your solution, which can also work:

```
   ((|))       ((|))
     |           |                       
   Phone       Laptop                 ((|))
                                        |
                                     PC Router---- Whatever provides your IN
                                       /
   Another device via Ethernet--------
```

You have replaced one device with a much more capable device. That is a good thing. There is also a down side: A regular PC is likely to draw much more power, make more noise, generate more heat etc.  In the long term this is probably not a wise financial investment. And if you want to connect your Ubuntu PC at the same time as you connect the windows PC you will also need a network card for that PC so you can use both at the same time. Either via adding a wireless card to the Ubunto PC, or by adding a second wired NIC to the PC router.

Having said that, yes, this can work. But it is almost never done and there are good reasons for it.

> Could you suggest one with link to amazon or best buy please?

Sadly no. Site policy. Also with good reasons. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional hotspot software (like [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/hotspot/)) to do this. Also, your computer needs to remain turned on all the times.

However, **if you want a hotspot, buy wireless router**, not another device that needs to be turned into a hotspot. Actually, I suggest you buy one now, regardless of whether you can or cannot return your WiFi card. Or else, you will end up paying more than that on your electric bill.

Comment: I am not sure he needs additional software.  Windows should be able to route traffic (think Internet connection sharing). And I know Ubuntu also can do this.

Comment: @Hennes I am pretty sure he does. There was a time when I had to make do with a wired router and a laptop that had a WiFi adapter, to provide Internet connection to my entire house... until my ASUS DSL-N10 unit arrived. I searched the nooks and crannies of the Internet for viable free solutions and I had to solve weird problems too.

Comment: Range from a wireless PC card is probly less than ideal. But as for as Linux is concerned it is merely another NIC. And you can define multiple subnets, setup routing, enable forwarding (`sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=` or `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`) and possibly set up a DHCP server.  No technical reason why you could not do this (it needs some knowledge or a good guide though). I know windows can do the same, though this might be stripped from home editions. A dedicated solution would be much easier though.

Comment: The biggest problem with giving a user a series of command line sequences or numbered instructions is that they are fragile moving parts, especially if they generate a lot of output that are no more meaningful than "Smiley face, Vampire, Werewolf, Palm Tree, Palm Tree, Palm Tree" or your meaningless word sequence of choice. One error, and the user is screwed. I mean, what if they are told that their NIC does not work in promiscuous mode?